# Weird behaviour of links - there is URL appended to every link displayed on page

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

Here's the problem:

Take a look at: http://postimage.org/image/zclhvutfl/

The question is how to get rid of appending the urls to links?? They are appended to every link in application. I.e. there should be only "Index" and "Time" word in the links, but there is also appended path to them. In Firebug I can see that everything is OK, but the links render as you see on above screenshot.

Im using Apache MyFaces and PrimeFaces on Tomcat 7. I already tried to remove PROJECT_STAGE=development from web.xml, but that was not the issue.

Comment: Duplicate of [URL appended to rendered link values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908487/url-appended-to-rendered-link-values). Please don't repost the same question over and over. As to the concrete problem, doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java/JSF, but more with the specific webbrowser.

Comment: I tried it in Chrome and FF, in both of them links are displayed the same way, so this is not a browser specific issue.

Comment: I just tried to put a simple <a> tag, and it was rendered also with URL... Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: it was just z blueprint css style for `<a>`

`a:link:after, a:visited:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    font-size: 90%;
}`

sounds funny, but I'm working with blueprint for one year now, but versions I had eariler didn't have this feature ;-)